# C2143 syntax error missing ';' before namespace

Tags: c++

I'm compiling a project that was originally developed using MSVC 2008. I'm trying to update it to MSVC 2017.  When I try to build I am seeing:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2143   syntax error : missing ';' before 'namespace'   Debug Service Group c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\yvals.h  568 
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Debug Service Group c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\yvals.h  568
```

I've been through the CPP and headers and I can't see anything obviously wrong, prototype:

```
#if !defined(DURATION_H)
#define DURATION_H
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// \class  Duration
/// \brief  Win32 implementation of the Duration class
///
class Duration {
public:
    /// \param  Duration of what we are trying to measure
    Duration(const std::string &a_str = "");
    /// Destructor outputs how long the object was alive
    ~Duration();

private:
    class Writer
    {
    public:                                     // Core is agnostic to the presence of outside world
        Writer(const std::string &a_fileName = "");
        void write(const std::string &a_text) const;
    private:
        std::string m_fileName;         ///< Output file name
    };

    unsigned long m_start;                      ///< Start time
    std::string m_str;                  ///< Duration of what we are trying to measure
};

#endif // defined(DURATION_H)
```

Implementation:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// \file   duration.cpp
/// \brief  Concrete (Win32) class implementing Duration
//
//  Revision history:
//
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

#include "duration.h"

#include "getwindows.h"

#pragma warning(disable: 4996)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// \class  Duration
/// \brief  Win32 implementation of the Duration class
///
Duration::Duration(const std::string &a_str) :
    m_start(GetTickCount()), m_str(a_str) {
}

/// Destructor outputs how long the object was alive
Duration::~Duration() {
    unsigned long elapsed(GetTickCount() - m_start);
    std::string strElapsed = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(elapsed);
    Writer w("timingstats.txt");
    w.write(m_str + " took: " + strElapsed);
}

Duration::Writer::Writer(const std::string &a_fileName) : m_fileName(a_fileName) {
}

void Duration::Writer::write(const std::string &a_text) const {
    if (m_fileName.length() > 0) {
        FILE *fd(fopen(m_fileName.c_str(), "ab"));
        if (fd) {                           // Open file in append mode, write the string
            std::string buf(a_text);        // and close the file asap
            buf += "\r\n";
            fwrite(buf.c_str(), buf.size(), 1, fd);
            fclose(fd);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\yvals.h  568` tells you the fault is in a header shipped with an old Visual Studio version.

That's unfortunately entirely expected to fail, as the old headers contain a lot of syntax errors which a non-conforming compiler like pre-VS2015 MSVC could still handle, and have only been completely fixed since VS2017.

For that reason, you will need not only to open your project in VS2017, but also change the active tool chain to V141 and to clean out all potentially hard coded paths to old include directories.

It may be faster to simply re-create the project from scratch in VS2017, and then only to re-add the existing source files.